# saving image to server with a download link

Tags: php, url, url-routing, fwrite, imagedownload

I have a code which generates the token url for image which upon hitting will directly download the image to a computer

It will be like

```
https://hostname.com/fa_get.php?p_parms=eUNF2GRLetC_2qKuSZxIxk6sb3UHy~IF01iZp5C6Rolvbqp2YG47aQAi2g3j~Hkisfz22pALVGxGnAG9Bj~IrwqT5gwg75werFbV1KzW3UuMJeJxE4t79YGoQJZQpVKIu_OsyGNMJLWbdY7ERqyxc7S~aIIeSgnAKX2zFsLqnDxVZ_HEctQwCxNQd2CrkF_ayc94PF3Wl_dgQzv3wgtFg7ZEOeCMOj0FC0WeYE4ZhcAPz5Iipds6qdyLqR2UDmp1JG25o0ayAyyWyaxcFgJFfZQQrVHc7tSQYI
```

I just want to download that image to a server folder `https://hostname.com/euf/assets/images/`

Don't want to use curl because no security involved , just want to take source url and destination url and move or download the file

Comment: let me know your server OS?

Comment: i have done this kind of work with linux based server

Comment: Oracle service cloud, Rightnow CX @MMaavia

Comment: sorry i have not work on oracle based server

Comment: No problem, Thanks for your time,. I think os doesn't matters here in OSvC

Comment: i have done it with this single line hope it will help you
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r'));
here Tmpfile.zip can be location of your server folder